# How do I ignore requests to a certain route in Sinatra when using NewRelic?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, newrelic

We're using NewRelic to monitor a Sinatra app. We don't want the probe URL varnish uses to check if the app is online to be instrumented by NewRelic. How do we tell NewRelic to ignore a certain Sinatra route? (The documentation only seems to refer to how to do this in Rails: https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/blocking-controller-instrumentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling `NewRelic::Agent.abort_transaction!` within the code path for the probe request. [See the API docs for details](http://newrelic.github.com/rpm/NewRelic/Agent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what their docs suggest https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/sinatra-support-in-the-ruby-agent

```
newrelic_ignore '/ping'
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.6.3 of the NewRelic gem, you <strike>can</strike> **should** be able to use the 'newrelic_ignore' method to ignore endpoints. <strike>If you are using Sinatra, you may need to call this class method explicitly, like so:</strike>

```
NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::Sinatra::newrelic_ignore('/route/to/ignore')
```

But, it doesn't work as expected. I am filing a bug report with NewRelic.

Comment: The forum posting is here if you'd like to follow: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/sinatra-newrelic-ignore-support-broken-in-newrelic-rpm-3-7-2-192/810

Comment: No, they never responded.